# Install IE 11 English in Windows 7 Chinese

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, language, internet-explorer-11, language-pack

I am using Windows 7 in Chinese. Previously it had an Internet Explorer 9 in Chinese.

But I want to use an Internet Explorer in English. From [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18520/download-internet-explorer-11-offline-installer), I have downloaded `English-English-Windows 7 SP1 64-bit`, the file name is `IE11-Windows6.1-x64-en-us.exe`, I installed it, now the version is `11`, but the language is still Chinese rather than English.

Does anyone know what I should do to install `Internet Explorer 11` in English?